# PHP session is not corresponding to current value in database

Tags: php, session

I have user information that I stored in array session **(only when user successfully login)**. When I update the user information using my web form, I realized that the user information that stored in session is not up to date with the database value.

Does that mean the session only memorizing those assigned data once till it meet with a function that replacing the data stored in session? So if I want to get the updated data from database, I need to keep re-assigned back the data session?

**EDIT**

I have this code in my `Homepage_controller` to fetch user information when they successfully login and store in session.

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $this->Homepage_model->fetchUser();
```

Then user will be redirected to `profile page` which is using different controller `User_account_controller` and from this controller I used to update user profile and will keep using the `$_SESSION['user']` that been set from the `Homepage_controller`

Comment: Can you show some code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can understand your post you are assigning session variables on login.
While you are logged in you change the data in database and want to update session variables?

If so you need to query database, retrieve new values and assign to session variables again.

Comment: Meaning to say the session value need to keep updated to get the current value from database.